# Get country specific app by restoring from iPad backup

Tags: restore, ipad

I have an iPad 3 that I bought while I was in India on which I have apps that I have purchased with an Indian credit card. When I came back to Singapore, I removed the Indian credit card information and added my Singapore card. I also updated my address to Singapore.

Now, the Singapore store does not have say for example, the Kindle app but the change in card or address did not remove any of my apps from the device.

I bought an iPad mini yesterday, logged in with the same Apple id but I am not able to install the Kindle app since it is not available in the Singapore store.

I want to know what would happen if I restore my iPad 3 backup onto my ipad mini. Will I be able to get back all the apps installed on the iPad 3 onto the mini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application data *is* included in backups. I would say that yes, if you restore a backup with that app on it you will have it back.

Comment: That's what I assumed. I am going to bite the bullet and try it. Better do it now when I dont have much stuff on the new iPad.

Comment: @BobbyAlexander Definitely man. Let me know if I can help with anything else. And, if this answer is correct that would be great if you could accept it!

Comment: aaaand... it just works.